# 'Stream' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a discord bot, where I need to retrieve a token from another file, but the code that I am using is throwing an error (see title/topic). The code I have is this:

```
string TOKEN = "";
using (var Stream = new FileStream((Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0", @"Data\Token.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
using (var ReadToken = new StreamReader(Stream)) {
    TOKEN = ReadToken.ReadToEnd();  
}
```

I'm sure the file is in the correct path, so I don't know what could've caused the error
Please let me know in the comments if I should provide more code!

Comment: `Stream` is a class name but you are trying to use it as a variable name.

Comment: Use lower case s for stream (not Stream)

Comment: I'm voting to close as `Off-topic because: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. ...`

Comment: I dunno, it's not really a typo so much as confusion as to what a particular compile error means. Maybe there's a dupe question for this...

Comment: The problem was that there isn't supposed to be a `;` in the first `using`, thank you for at least contributing with solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Typical C# convention is to use `camelCase`-style identifier names for local variables, which helps protect you from unintentionally naming your variables the same as some types that are in scope.

Declaring a variable with the same name as another identifier *is* supported, so why is the compiler confused? It's because your first `using` statement has a `;`, which is restricting the scope of that `Stream` variable to *just* the `using` statement. Therefore, in the `new StreamReader(Stream)` expression, the compiler thinks `Stream` refers to the `Stream` type that's in scope, not the variable it no-longer knows about.

Recommended changes:

```
var token = "";
using (var stream = new FileStream((Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0", @"Data\Token.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var readToken = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    token = readToken.ReadToEnd();  
}
```

...or to make the using scopes less confusing, you can explicitly use braces to make things clearer:

```
var token = "";
using (var stream = new FileStream((Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Replace(@"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0", @"Data\Token.txt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    using (var readToken = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        token = readToken.ReadToEnd();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing that, but it returned `The name 'stream' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Did you fix the variable at the point where it is declared as well? It has to be changed at the `var` declaration as well as its usage in `new StreamReader(...)`.

Comment: It had nothing to do with the variable name actually :D It was the `;`, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could shadow the `Stream` type with a variable declaration. Probably not a good idea, though, since if you're wanting to share this code with others, when they see a `PascalCase` identifier, they assume it's a type or object member.

Comment: Updated answer so it's actually accurate.

Comment: Upvoted after edit and undeletion. While it is unusual to use a capital initial letter for a local variable, the local variable will have precedence over that type (which is defined "further out") in contexts where it could be unclear if a type of a value is required. However, the scope of a variable declared in a `using` statement is the body of the `using` statement, and as you correctly explained, with an empty statement `;` present, the scope of the `using` variable ends with that empty statement.